# encoding and decoding using VideoToolBox

Tags: cocoa, encoding, decoding, video-toolbox

I'm writing a Mac app that encodes AVCaptureVideoDataOutput with H264 using videotoolbox framework.

```
VTCompressionSessionRef session;
OSStatus ret = VTCompressionSessionCreate(NULL, (int)width, (int)height, kCMVideoCodecType_H264, NULL, NULL, NULL, OutputCallback, NULL, &session);
```

The callback is implemented like this:

```
void OutputCallback(void *outputCallbackRefCon,
            void *sourceFrameRefCon,
            OSStatus status,
            VTEncodeInfoFlags infoFlags,
            CMSampleBufferRef sampleBuffer) 
{

    CMBlockBufferRef block = CMSampleBufferGetDataBuffer(sampleBuffer);
    char* bufferData;
    size_t size;

    CMBlockBufferGetDataPointer(block, 0, NULL, &size, &bufferData);
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytes:bufferData length:size];
    //and i use this data 

}
```

Have these warnings in log

```
GVA warning: init, skip trailing zeros pps size = 35
```

GVA warning: init, skip trailing zeros pps size = 34
GVA warning: AVF_Get_Standalone_PPS, skip trailing zeros pps size = 35

Can anyone suggest a better way to decode to display in AVSampleBufferdisplayLayer?

Comment: What exactly is not working / which errors do you get?

Comment: @sandeep have used this encode and decode and its working fine,provide more info so i can help

Comment: error here while decompress CMVideoFormatDescriptionCreateFromH264ParameterSets with error code -12712 , i follow this code https://mobisoftinfotech.com/resources/mguide/h264-encode-decode-using-videotoolbox/                                                                             
 status = CMVideoFormatDescriptionCreateFromH264ParameterSets(kCFAlloc‌ atorDefault, 2, (const uint8_t const)parameterSetPointers, parameterSetSizes, 4, &_formatDesc);

Comment: https://github.com/acsandeep/videoCompressionTest                                             This is the test app; can anyone figure out the problem with this code.